# This webpage has a redirect loop, I've tried every available fix, none of them worked

Tags: php, apache

I know what you're going to tell me 'google it'.

I have!

Including these 2 links

https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-pset7

https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/3prpbn/pset7_without_the_appliance_and_too_many_redirects/

None of these fixes worked. I don't know what else to do.

This is my config.php untouched

```
// display errors, warnings, and notices
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// requirements
require("helpers.php");

// CS50 Library
require("../vendor/library50-php-5/CS50/CS50.php");
CS50::init(__DIR__ . "/../config.json");

// enable sessions
session_start();

// require authentication for all pages except /login.php, /logout.php, and /register.php
if (!in_array($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ["/login.php", "/logout.php", "/register.php"]))
{
    if (empty($_SESSION["id"]))
    {
        redirect("login.php");
    }
}
```

The files are placed in `/home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/public/finance/`

Comment: What is the value of `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` for the page you are getting the redirect loop on?

Comment: @Chris whenever I goto `http://localhost/finance/public/` it redirects me to `http://localhost/finance/public/login.php` and I get the error. And the value for `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is `/finance/public/test.php` - I've created a `test.php` for that purpose.

Comment: put `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; die();` before IF statement and check what is the value of it.

Comment: So almost certainly the value for your login page is `/finance/public/login.php`, which is not in your array. Because of this you will be redirected.

Comment: Is this not obvious? `/finance/public/test.php` NOT EQUAL TO `/login.php` Nor is `/finance/public/login.php` EQUAL TO `/login.php` _Hence the eternal redirect loop_

Comment: Yes, it's obvious now. Thanks.